# Arabic words shown as question marks in wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, arabic

I've wordpress website what fetch arabic data and displays without any problems.
But If I made echo "محمد"; it will appear as question mark (??????).
I've changed charset in header.php of my theme to utf-8 but also the same happens.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: See if your font also supports Unicode fonts. The problem is because of the font not supporting the Unicode, or the characters being encoded using any other format (UTF-32, UTF-16 etc.). There are many factors that can cause such problems.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I didn't change font. It's the default font of wordpress.

Comment: Thanks Azfaal,The problem was in my IDE. It changes the charset of the file.

Comment: Can you add that as an answer?